# Dominance Law in Boolean Algebra

Tags: algebra

The dominance law states that **x + 1 = 1**

If we go by that logic, does that mean that **x' + 1 = 1?**

Please just tell me if it's a yes(as I think that this is the answer but I just want to clear my doubts) and maybe provide a little explanation if it's a no.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. $\ \quad\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x+1=1$ then, substituting $x'$ for $x$, we deduce that $x'+1=1$.

In other words, your claim follows from the fact that $x'$ has the same "type" as $x$.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

In Boolean Algebra, '+' is synonymous to '∪' (**union**), and your problem can be illustrated as the '**or**' logic gate to better understand it:

[image: OR Gate]

If we allow *B* to be 1, *Z* is always 1, regardless of the state of *A* (in your case, it could be X or X').